# Changing the selected index of tabbar controller displays a black screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to navigate from one view controller to another using this code:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![1]
```

When the code executes it goes to the desired `UIViewController` but the view appears after a small delay and a black screen is visible during that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer just had to run the code in main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
  self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![1]
}
```

}